# The replace function is replacing words multiple times and combining words. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a dictionary of words to replace in excel and am using it to replace many words at once in Python. However, words are being replaced multiple times and even forming new words from two words.

I've been using the replace() function

```
#  dictionary
all_synonyms = alias_all['Synonyms']
all_standard = alias_all['Standard']
dictionary = dict(zip(all_synonyms,all_standard))
#print(dictionary)


df= df.replace(dictionary, regex=True)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
print(df.loc[97])
```

In my text, I want

```
mag plug
```

to replace with

```
magnetic plug
```

(as I defined in my dictionary)

However

```
mag plug
```

is replacing as

```
magnetic plug magnetic plugnetic plug
```

Comment: What is `alias_all`? Can you post an example please? It could be a case where your regex is incorrect and therefor matching multiple times.

Comment: alias_all is an excel sheet with two columns, the first being words that I want replaced, the second being what I want to replace each word with

Comment: I'm not sure what regex does, but I could not get anything to replace without including regex=True

Comment: It makes it match the original string as a regular expression rather than a fixed string.

Comment: If you want to match whole words, use `\b` to match word boundaries, like `\bmag\b`. Then it won't match `mag` at the beginning of `magnetic`.

Comment: Regex = Regular Expression. It's a way to specify the way a match should be considered. It is almost a programming language in itself.

Comment: would I add the boundaries to every one of my inputs in the excel sheet? Also, would I add that to both columns?

Comment: You only need to add it to the pattern, not the replacement. You should add it to any of the inputs that you want to be matched as whole words.

Comment: adding the /b before and after is stopping the word from getting replaced at all